# Email notification on Huawei Mate 9 Pro

Tags: notifications

How can I get email Notification on my Huawei Mate 9 Pro? Used to have it but now it has disappeared. No sound is heard and no icon shows up for incoming emails.
Any comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Gmail client for Android, then as documented on the [Google support page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1075549?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en):

By default, notifications are turned on for any messages in your Primary label.

#### First, turn on notifications & choose your settings

1. Open the Gmail app [image: Gmail].
2. In the top left, tap Menu [image: Menu].
3. Tap **Settings**.
4. Select your account.
5. To turn on notifications, check the box next to "Notifications."
6. Tap **Inbox sound & vibrate**.
7. Choose your notification settings, including sounds.

**Note:** Your Android device also has [notification settings](http://help.google.com/nexus/answer/6111294) that are separate from the Gmail app.

#### Change notification settings for certain labels

1. Open the Gmail app [image: Gmail].
2. In the top left, tap Menu [image: Menu].
3. Tap **Settings**.
4. Select your account.
5. Tap **Manage Labels**.
6. Tap one of your labels, like **Important**.
7. Tap **Sync messages** [image: and then] **Last 30 days** or **All**. If you don't sync messages, you can't turn on notifications for that label.
8. Choose your notification settings for that label. Repeat this for any labels you want to get notifications for.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info on Gmail Client. However I am also using the Email Client on my Device as I have a POP3 email adress. On this Client the Notification seems to be missing With both sound and icon. Also want to use the Outlook app and the same seems to be the problem there. Your note: Your Android device also has notification settings that are separate from the Gmail app. The link did not work. Could you check the link "Notification settings"?